# derivative of closed parametric curve

Tags: real-analysis, parametric, plane-curves

Suppose, a parametric function $\beta:[0,1]\mapsto\mathbb{R}^2$ is a closed curve, that is $\beta(0)=\beta(1)$. For example $\beta(t)=(\sin 2\pi t,\cos 2\pi t)'$.

Then my question: Is the derivative $\beta'(t)$ is also closed curve?
For the above example $\beta'(t)=(2\pi\cos 2\pi t,-2\pi \sin 2\pi t)'$.

Could any one please suggest me what is the answer and how to prove it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is in general wrong. The curve $[0,2\pi]\ni t\mapsto (\sin (\tfrac{t}{2})\cos (\tfrac{t}{2}),\sin (\tfrac{t}{2}))$ provides a counter-example.

Answer (score 1):

Being closed has nothing to do with it. At any sharp point on the curve, the curve traced by the derivative will be discontinuous. The start/end point is not in any way special, it's just a matter of having a parametric curve with a continuous derivative. You could have a closed curve that is continuously differentiable at start/end point, but has a cusp somewhere else.

Comment: The question is about the derivative at $t$ (as a function) of closed curve is a closed curve or not. How it can be answered by the your explanation? Could you please explain.

Comment: If the function has a discontinuous derivative at any point (either in somewhere in the middle or at the "stitching point"), the curve will be discontinuous there. Geometrically this means that the curve should not have sharp points (angular singularities). Analytically, the derivative in all three components should be continuous and match at the beginning and at the end. Note that this is stricter than the absence of sharp corners, as the magnitude of the derivative may not match between the initial and final point (reparametrization can help with that).